# Is it possible to add to an Alexa Skill a custom dictionary to enhance and precise the speech-to-text transcription?

Tags: speech-recognition, alexa-skills-kit, speech-to-text

I have developed an Alexa skill, but its speech-to-text transformation is not precise enough for my backend. I have intents like "*Whats the* `{playername}`*'s performance*". These player names are real nicknames, so they are kind of tricky to be analysed. Is there a possibility to add like specific words to the skill to enhance precision, so it first tries to match vocals to these set of words?

Up to now I didn't find any information in any documentation. I'm generally new to working with Alexa skills.

So instead of "*How many goals did the* `jeep king` *score?*", there should be precious word matching, so ideally I get a result like "*How many goals did* `TGKing` *score*?"

I hope it's understandable what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexa [custom slot types](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html) might be an appropriate solution to adopt.

The custom slot types is an extension of the [slot types](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#list-slot-types) already built into the Alexa Skills Kit. If you're using English (US), you might find that one of the already defined slot types are enough, i.e. `AMAZON.Athlete`, `AMAZON.Person`, or `AMAZON.Professional`.

Use this in your sample utterances by, for example, specifying `nameOfPerson` as the "*intent slot*" with `AMAZON.Athlete` as the "*slot type*". So in the example you provided, the sample utterance would be "*What's the* `{nameOfPerson}`*'s performance*"

If the built-in types aren't specific enough, you can use the custom slot types to define your own type, which you could call for example `player`. When creating the slot type `player`, you will specify every player you want to include and you can also enter any synonyms (e.g. nicknames) which should match to the player.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.htm) - which provides an insight into how to [edit and upload custom slot type values in bulk](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html#json-for-slot-types-interaction-model-schema), as well as how to [extend the built-in slot types](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html#json-for-slot-types-interaction-model-schema) with additional values.

Comment: That's exactly that I was searching for. I was not familiar with the concept of slots for Alexa Skills. Thank you ☺️.